# How to Reset CSS after Media Query?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have some elements on my page that display and some that hide via a media query, and ultimately the nav disappears and is replaced by a responsive jQuery menu. This all works great, but when I resize the browser after, some of the elements that where once hidden are not not. This is what I have for the media query

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width: 1282px) 
{ 
#wrapMiddleNew { display:block; }
    }
```

I essintially want to hide it again on the same breakpoint sizing back up. This doesn't seem to work.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width: 1282px) 
{ 
#wrapMiddleNew { display:none; }
}
```

Comment: I won't pretend this is an answer, but are those the only two media queries you're using? I would leave the first media query out and put that CSS in the base CSS file, then have only the min-width media query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got trough your page and you have to add more query format.. this should do the trick

```
/* Normal Formating */
#wrapLeft, #wrapMiddle, #wrapRight {
     display:block;
}

#breakNav {
     display:none;
}
/* Media Query */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1282px) {
      #wrapLeft, #wrapRight {
          display:none;
      }
     #breakNav {
          display:block;
     }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
     #wrapLeft, #wrapRight, #breakNav {
     display:none;
}

}
```

So each time your window goes lower 1282px will apear if its bigger will hide....

Comment: Sorry my question isn't completely clear. The queries I'm using work, but after the JS menu kicks in, and enlarging the browser, the orginally hidden #wrapMiddleNew does not revert back to its hidden state. See here what I mean http://www.gregtaylordesignstudio.com/Great-Lakes-Project/great_lakes_working.html

Comment: Thank you, what is strange is it works once. But if you shrink and enlarge the browser a second time the #breakNav does not hide again

Comment: Make the change in your online webpage so I can see what extra code you have that's messing with it...

Comment: OK now I see whats happening, I think you got a Jquery thats adding style="display: block;" in the html because media quieries doesn't add that, so change that div ID name to another name and change it in your css adn queries, or if you got a jquery that calls #breakNav in resize delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 #wrapMiddleNew{
    display:none;
 }
 @media only screen  and (max-width: 1282px) 
 { 
      #wrapMiddleNew { display:block; }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry my question isn't completely clear. The queries I'm using work, but after the JS menu kicks in, and enlarging the browser, the orginally hidden #wrapMiddleNew does not revert back to its hidden state. See here what I mean http://www.gregtaylordesignstudio.com/Great-Lakes-Project/great_lakes_working.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second query as the first bit of css only comes into effect while the screen is less than a certain number here is a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/WZXM6/

CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    .hi {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Here is a media query tutorial:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

You are targeting the wrong div your query should look like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1282px) { 
    #breakNav { 
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Then remove any jquery affecting that element

Comment: Sorry my question isn't completely clear. The queries I'm using work, but after the JS menu kicks in, and enlarging the browser, the orginally hidden #wrapMiddleNew does not revert back to its hidden state. See here what I mean http://www.gregtaylordesignstudio.com/Great-Lakes-Project/great_lakes_working.html