# CSS @media property can't reverse after conditional no longer applies

Tags: html, css

I am using the CSS @media property to hide a div when the page is 900px or less in width. It works the first because when I resize the page to less than 901px the div disappears, but when I return the page to its normal size, the div remains hidden. Here is the code:

```
<style>
        .mydiv {
           display:block
        }
        @media (max-width: 900px) { 
        .mydiv { 
          display: none;
        } 
      }
     
     
</style>
```

What do I have to do to make the div reappear after the size returns to normal?

Comment: You need to set `.mydiv` to display again `block, inline-block` whatever. Since you didn't provide any other code, I'm guessing that you don't have that. The CSS doesn't know to return an element back to its original state, unless you tell it to. Just add `mydiv { display: block }` directly above that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Reset CSS after Media Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284002/how-to-reset-css-after-media-query)

Comment: I have tried these things and they don't seem to work

Comment: There is a missing semi-colon `display: block` in your code @JackieSoussan

Comment: This code should work. You may have something else going on. I see you set `visibility` instead, but that probably isn't the correct fix and you need to find the root of the cause.

Comment: @geauser the missing semicolon won't matter in a single property rule. Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/3vytgaq0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed it by using `visibility: hidden` instead of using `display: none.` I don't know if this is a consistent fix, but it worked for me

Comment: Note that `visibility: hidden` is simply making an element invisible but the element is still here and is still taking up space. `display: none` actually "removes" the element from the display flow making it effectively disappear

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<style>
    .mydiv { 
      display: block;
    } 

    @media (max-width: 900px) { 
    .mydiv { 
      display: none;
    } 
  }
 
 
</style>
```

Comment: Can you add the html code of the divs with the class ".mydiv"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a style interfering somewhere, you may want to look at the inspector to see which styles are being applied.

*(open the snippet in expanded mode to test it)*

```css
.hide-me {
  width:  200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green; /* visible */
}

/* This has to come last */
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .hide-me {
    background: red; /* hidden */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hide-me"></div>
```

Comment: The code snippet works perfectly, but when I apply it to my code it does nothing. I am quite confused.

Comment: Can you post the full version of the relevant sections of the CSS stylesheet @JackieSoussan? I'm pretty sure there is something you missed also look at the Chrome inspector and look if there is no missing semi-colons in your styles